# How do you make an MVC Webgrid show multiple lines in a cell?

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, webgrid

I have a function in code that generates a string `A\nB\nC`, when it is pulled into my Webgrid, I use a function on the Razor side to change the `\n` to a `<br />`, and I know this works because in the webpage source it shows the string on three separate lines.

`@functions {
    public static string ReplaceLineBreaks(string s) {
        return s.Replace(Environment.NewLine, "@Html.Raw(<br />)");
    }
}`

`<div id="grid_MyWebGrid">
    @grid.GetHtml(
        tableStyle : "table",
        alternatingRowStyle : "alternate",
        headerStyle : "header",
        columns: grid.Columns(
            grid.Column("Letters", format: item => 
                @Html.Raw(ReplaceLineBreaks(Html.Encode(item.Letters)))),
        )
    )
</div>`

But when I load the page, the cell for that column shows:

`ABC`

Instead of:

`A
B
C`

Is there something in WebGrid that lets you tell it that that column is to be used as a multi-line cell?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found something called a `@helper` that will you can use to design Razor inline templates.
Using a `@helper`, I wrote a `foreach` statement that would create `spans` for each of the strings.

`@helper DisplayMultiLine(string str) {
    foreach(string s in str.Split(new char[] {'\n'})) {
        @s <br />
    }
}`

`<div id="grid_searchentities">
    @grid.GetHtml(
        tableStyle : "table",
        alternatingRowStyle : "alternate",
        headerStyle : "header",
        columns: grid.Columns(
            grid.Column("Letters", 
                 format:@<text>@DisplayMultiLine(@item.Letters)</text>),
        )
    )
</div>`